# Using a Sparse Matrix with sklearn Affinity Propagation

Tags: python, scipy, scikit-learn, sparse-matrix

I am having problems with using a scipy COO sparse matrix as an input for Affinity propagation, but it works perfectly fine with a numpy array.

Just an example, say my similarity matrix is:

```
[[1.0, 0.9, 0.2]
 [0.9, 1.0, 0.0]
 [0.2, 0.0, 1.0]]
```

Numpy matrix version

```
import numpy as np
import sklearn.cluster

simnp = np.array([[1,0.9,0.2],[0.9,1,0],[0.2,0,1]])
affprop = sklearn.cluster.AffinityPropagation(affinity="precomputed")
affprop.fit(simnp)
```

works as expected.

Sparse Matrix version

```
import scipy.sparse as sps
import sklearn.cluster

simsps = sps.coo_matrix(([1,1,1,0.9,0.9,0.2,0.2],([0,1,2,0,1,0,2],[0,1,2,1,0,2,0])),(3,3))
affprop = sklearn.cluster.AffinityPropagation(affinity="precomputed")
affprop.fit(simsps)
```

returns the following error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Python\Python27\lib\site-packages\sklearn\cluster\affinity_propagation_.py", line 301, in fit
    copy=self.copy, verbose=self.verbose, return_n_iter=True)
  File "C:\Python\Python27\lib\site-packages\sklearn\cluster\affinity_propagation_.py", line 90, in affinity_propagation
    preference = np.median(S)
  File "C:\Python\Python27\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\function_base.py", line 3084, in median
    overwrite_input=overwrite_input)
  File "C:\Python\Python27\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\function_base.py", line 2997, in _ureduce
    r = func(a, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python\Python27\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\function_base.py", line 3158, in _median
    return mean(part[indexer], axis=axis, out=out)
  File "C:\Python\Python27\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\fromnumeric.py", line 2878, in mean
    out=out, keepdims=keepdims)
  File "C:\Python\Python27\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\_methods.py", line 70, in _mean
    ret = ret.dtype.type(ret / rcount)
ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.
```

My laptop does not have enough RAM to take a dense matrix thus wanting to use a sparse matrix.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: In general, `numpy` functions (such as `median`) are not sparse matrix aware.  Somethings work because they delegate the task to a sparse method.  Does `sklearn` say you can use a sparse matrix in this way?

Comment: Hi, I just implied it from a line in their website: 

"Further, the memory complexity is of the order O(N^2) if a dense similarity matrix is used, but reducible if a sparse similarity matrix is used."

http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/clustering.html#affinity-propagation

What I did was to convert the sparse matrix to an array with the '.toarray()' method when I pass it the array through sklearn's 'fit()' method. I'm not quite sure if I was able to reduce the memory impact. I still have to test it some more.

Thanks!

Comment: A sparse matrix is probably not useful, for memory or speed, unless the sparsity, proportion of nonzero values to  total, is 1% or less.

Comment: Hi, thanks for looking into this. I was just estimating the impact of using a sparse matrix on the `sys.getsizeof()` function. For the algorithm, I was planning on making the value 0 if it was less than 0.3 since that would have been a bad match anyway. I guess I'll just have to convert it back to a dense matrix before passing it to the sklearn methods. 

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.cluster.AffinityPropagation.html

> fit(X, y=None)
>   Parameters:
>   X: array-like, shape (n_samples, n_features) or (n_samples, n_samples)
>
> predict(X)
>   Parameters:
>   X : {array-like, sparse matrix}, shape (n_samples, n_features)

http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.cluster.SpectralClustering.html

> fit(X, y=None)
>   Parameters:
>   X : array-like or sparse matrix, shape (n_samples, n_features)

So some of the methods do accept a sparse matrix. But the `AffinityPropagation.fit` does not make that claim.  Is that a documentation omission, or an indication that it does not work with a sparse matrix?  Your error indicates the latter - for one reason or other, it has not been adapted to work with sparse.

I'm not a user of `scikit-learn`, but have answered a few questions about sparse matrices in that package.  My impression is the handling sparse is relatively new, and that in some cases they have to use `todense()` to turn the sparse ones back into dense matrices.

Like I wrote in my comment, `numpy` code, by itself, does not handle sparse matrices correctly.  It only works if it delegates the action to sparse methods.  It appears that `np.median` and `np.mean` do not properly delegate to `sparse.coo_matrix.mean`.

Try:

```
np.median(simnp)
np.mean(simnp)
simnp.mean()
```

Answer (score 0):

An update on current status of sklearn (June 2019) could be useful.

Already at the time of original question there was a [fix](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/pull/4054) of an [issue](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues/4051) reporting that AffinityPropagation was not working with sparse matrices. Recently (May 2019) it was [reported again](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues/13812) that AffinityPropagation was not working with sparse matrices.

The summary actually is:

- the fit works with sparse matrix only if affinity is not precomputed but Euclidean (since it calls sklearn.metrics.euclidean_distances which works with sparse matrices). This actually gives no advantage in term of memory consumption.
- if affinity is precomputed instead the fit will not work with sparse matrix. the current blocking line of code seems to be a computation of median.